# How to diagnose the source of bathroom leakage with minimum damage

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, leak, moisture, grout

Today we notices some discoloration/stains under our stairway, next to our upstairs bathroom:

I removed the wooden cover of the piping system, which was mostly soaked/rotten

I think the source of the leakage is between the shower sewage pipe and the cement floor/ceiling. This is a horrible practice from a maintainability point of view. Quite often I wonder why Dutch architects have no regard for maintainability!

Anyway, now I have to find what is the root cause of the leakage. I am checking the silicon sealing and grout between the tiles in the shower, but I don't think there are any issues:

However, some of the grouts in the shower and below the toilet seat right beside the shower are brownish:

This indicates that there might be some internal leakage either from the toilet siphon or the sewage piping. Now I am wondering what is the most minimally invasive method to find the source of leakage. I don't want to remove the grouts/silicons, as it is damaging, time-consuming, and disruptive. Is it worth the money to buy/rent an inspection camera and send it through the sewage piping or inside the built-in siphon? I have no prior knowledge of piping. please advise me on what to do.

Comment: Would it be easier to check from the other side of the wall?  If lucky the other side is just drywall and a bit easier to repair.  If very lucky there is an access panel/door.  Think you would have a better chance of seeing a leak from the outside of the pipes than from the inside, Leaks are usually from quite tiny holes/cracks.

Comment: And remember water drips can run along pipes for some distance.

Comment: @crip659 not possible. we live in one of these rijtjeshuis where we share the wall with a neighbor.

Comment: @SolarMike so practically I have to dig all along the pipe. 

Comment: Will the cover for the flush handle come off?  Might be able to get an inspection in there and see if any leaks around.

Comment: @crip659 yes it does. That's what I am thinking of actually. Any suggestion for one of those inspection cameras? are they any good?

Comment: Check with your neighbors they may be having a problem as well and possibly the fault could be there's.

Comment: Have never used one but people seem to think they are useful for seeing inside of walls/tight places.  The cameras on them are small to fit into small holes(easier to fix).  Online stores should be able to let you see what is available, might also be able to rent one, but do not think you would save much from buying.

Comment: @Gil hmm, , that's highly unlikely. There is a thick beton wall between the houses. And they bought the house pretty recently. The former owner did a renovation. I am gonna ask anyway...

Comment: Start by inspecting the moving parts like the shower valve, remove the cover and inspect it. Water always flows downwards, so the source has to be up from the visible leak. That is not a toilet siphon leak

Comment: Start  by putting a dye such as sodium fluorescein (e.g., https://chaostrade.eu/fluorescein-200-sodium-salt) in the toilet, let it sit for a day, flush, and check below with a UV flashlight (e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Flashlight-Portable-Ultraviolet-Detector-Batteries/dp/B00GU55270). If there's no seepage visible, try around the other fixtures and their drain pipes.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik this is an amazing idea. This is the kind of technology that I am looking for. I am gonna give it a try.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I just bought [this](https://www.amazon.nl/-/en/dp/B07JG1LSCR?smid=A3W4MDETDY4HDJ&ref_=chk_typ_imgToDp&th=1) Uranine and [this](https://www.amazon.nl/-/en/gp/product/B072MGHYH2/ref=sw_img_1?smid=AYK3HBVM2WGCR&th=1) UV flash light.